# Multivariable Regression: t vs. z to determine relative significance

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have a multivariable regression model that includes 4 independent variables.  I would like to determine relative significance between the variables.

The 't stat' is given by the software.  Can I simply use these values to compare relative significance?

Alternatively, I read that standardized regression coefficients should be found to determine relative significance (https://www.real-statistics.com/multiple-regression/standardized-regression-coefficients/)

The results are nearly but not exactly the same.  Which approach is more appropriate?

Comment: Please explain what you might mean by "relative significance:" what do you hope such a quantity will help you do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the $t$-statistic to compare relative significance.  The $t$-statistic is scale-independent, so the absolute value of large vs. small values, i.e., $|t_j|$, across coefficients will reflect relative significance.  For regression, the t-statistic for the $j$th predictor variable is

\begin{equation}
t_j=\frac{\beta_j}{\mathrm{s.e.}(\beta_j)},
\end{equation}

where $\beta_j$ is the regression coefficient, and $\mathrm{s.e.}(\beta_j)$ is the standard error of $\beta_j$.

The t-statistics won't change if you run regression on standardized variables, but the regression coefficients will.  So what you are asking, about standardized coefficients, will only result in a change in the coefficients, $\beta_j$, but not $t_j$ statistics.

For the sake of efficiency, I found this good example write-up on your question:

[https://www.statology.org/standardized-vs-unstandardized-regression-coefficients/#:~:text=Standardized%20regression%20coefficients%20are%20useful%20when%20you%20want,has%20the%20greatest%20effect%20on%20the%20response%20variable](https://www.statology.org/standardized-vs-unstandardized-regression-coefficients/#:%7E:text=Standardized%20regression%20coefficients%20are%20useful%20when%20you%20want,has%20the%20greatest%20effect%20on%20the%20response%20variable).

Comment: Unfortunately, the meaning of "relative significance" is obscure in this context, because unless the variables are mutually orthogonal, all parameter estimates and their t-values depend on the context and have little independent meaning. For instance, the model might be extremely *sensitive* to the values of two mutually correlated explanatory variables that almost completely account for the response, yet the t-statistics for those two variables could be nearly zero due to that correlation.  This shows how dramatically wrong a comparison of t-statistics can be.